# Python 3 - Global Variables with AsyncIO/APScheduler

Tags: python, global-variables, global, python-asyncio, apscheduler

Been struggling with this for a while.

Based on this thread: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

I should be able to update the variable used by thread_2 by scheduling a task at certain times.

The code:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from datetime import datetime
import time


def day_limits():

        global variable
        variable = 90
        print ('Day Variable: ',variable)

def night_limits():

        global variable
        variable = 65
        print ('Night Variable: ',variable)


def thread_2():


    while True:

        c_hour = int(datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
        c_min = int(datetime.now().strftime("%M"))
        c_sec = int(datetime.now().strftime("%S"))

        print ('%02d:%02d:%02d - Variable: %d ' % (c_hour,c_min,c_sec,variable))

        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    variable = 60

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(day_limits, 'cron', hour=7,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.add_job(night_limits, 'cron', hour=19, minute=32,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.start()

    scheduler.print_jobs()

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(1)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    baa = asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_2))


    try:
        loop.run_forever()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception):
        loop.stop()
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

Results in:

```
19:31:54 - Variable: 60 
19:31:56 - Variable: 60 
19:31:58 - Variable: 60    
Night Variable:  65
19:32:00 - Variable: 60 
19:32:02 - Variable: 60
```

I am missing something, but I can't see what!

Thoughts?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this your complete code snippet? Don't understand where the functions are being called?

Comment: At the bottom in the main area. Two are called via APscheduler, and run correctly. Final thing is a thread by asyncio (baa line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, you need to use a process-safe object in place of an ordinary integer. If you only need to support Linux (and can therefore rely on having `fork()`), you can just use an ordinary, global [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) to do this.

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from datetime import datetime
import time


def day_limits():
        variable.value = 90
        print ('Day Variable: ',variable.value)

def night_limits():
        variable.value = 65
        print ('Night Variable: ',variable.value)


def thread_2():
    while True:
        c_hour = int(datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
        c_min = int(datetime.now().strftime("%M"))
        c_sec = int(datetime.now().strftime("%S"))

        print ('%02d:%02d:%02d - Variable: %d ' % (c_hour,c_min,c_sec,variable.value))

        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    variable = multiprocessing.Value('i', 60)

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(day_limits, 'cron', hour=7,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.add_job(night_limits, 'cron', hour=19, minute=32,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.start()

    scheduler.print_jobs()

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(1)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    baa = asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_2))


    try:
        loop.run_forever()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception):
        loop.stop()
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

If you need to support both Windows and Linux, you'll need to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) to create the [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Value) object, and explicitly pass that object to the function you're running in the `Executor`:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from datetime import datetime
import time


def day_limits():
        variable.value = 90
        print ('Day Variable: ',variable.value)

def night_limits():
        variable.value = 65
        print ('Night Variable: ',variable.value)


def thread_2(variable):
    while True:
        c_hour = int(datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
        c_min = int(datetime.now().strftime("%M"))
        c_sec = int(datetime.now().strftime("%S"))

        print ('%02d:%02d:%02d - Variable: %d ' % (c_hour,c_min,c_sec,variable.value))

        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    variable = m.Value('i', 60)

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(day_limits, 'cron', hour=7,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.add_job(night_limits, 'cron', hour=19, minute=32,misfire_grace_time=3600,timezone='GB')
    scheduler.start()

    scheduler.print_jobs()

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(1)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    baa = asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_2, variable))  # Need to pass variable explicitly

    try:
        loop.run_forever()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception):
        loop.stop()
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

Because Windows lacks `fork` support, you need to explicitly pass the `Value` to the function you're running in the `Executor`. If you don't, the child process will say that the variable doesn't exist. However, since you're explicitly passing the `Value` to the `run_in_executor` method, you can't use an ordinary `multiprocessing.Value` - you'll get a `RuntimeError` saying that "Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance".

Using the `multiprocessing.Manager` works around this; the `multiprocessing.Manager` starts a process that can create and managed process-shared objects. Calling `m.Value()` returns a `Proxy` to a shared `Value`, and that `Proxy` can be passed to `run_in_executor` without raising an exception.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this was what I needed!
But, as a word of warning, if anyone expects to be able to use the `.get_lock` method: https://bugs.python.org/issue35786, apparently it just straight up doesn't exist for the Manager version... and also all those other problems the bug reporter wrote about in the comments

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple: You are using ProcessPoolExecutor. So the jobs are run in another process, which has its own memory space. `variable` is set correctly there, but it has a different value (60) in the parent process, which is never changed.

Comment: I thought it probably was due to that. What is the solution? Some sort of pointer?